# Python script under daemontools does not get signal 15

Tags: python, daemon

I have a python script which I want to run as a daemon under daemontools. Usually the service running under deamontools runs in foreground and if it goes down, daemontools will restart it.  The service should also handle signals as described [here](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/svc.html).

My program catches `SIGINT` and `SIGALRM` and when the signals are received program exits.

When the program is run from command line and `kill -1 <pid>` and `kill -15 <pid>` is signaled, the signal handler is run, which causes program to exit,  and corresponding logs are printed.

But when the program is run under daemontools, and `svc -d /service/myrogram` is executed, the program neither exits nor logs are printed.

I am using following `run` script to run the program under daemontools

```bash
#!/bin/sh
exec 2>&1
/usr/bin/python /home/test/sigtest.py
```

I am wondering why `kill -15 <pid>` works while `svc -d /service/myrogram` does not seems to deliver the signal to the python program.

The python script I am working with is:

```python
from pyudev import Context, Monitor, MonitorObserver
import signal, sys, time

def print_device_event(device):
    print ('New event - {0.action}: {0.device_path}'.format(device))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    context = Context()
    monitor = Monitor.from_netlink(context)
    observer = MonitorObserver(monitor, callback=print_device_event, name='monitor-observer')
    print ("Processing started")
    observer.start()
    def handler(signum, frame):
        print("Received Signal: %d"%signum)
        observer.send_stop()
        print("Exiting.")
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, handler)

    try:
        while observer.is_alive():
            observer.join(timeout=1.0)
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        print("Caught KeyboardInterrupt, exiting")
        observer.send_stop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am using following run script to run the program under daemontools
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> exec 2>&1
> /usr/bin/python /home/test/sigtest.py
> ```

And there's your error.  You're forking a child process to run the python program in.  *Stop your daemon from forking.*   Daemons do not need to, and should not, fork to run in a child process, be they running under daemontools, [daemontools-encore](http://untroubled.org/daemontools-encore/), [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/), [s6](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/), [perp](http://b0llix.net/perp/), or even [systemd](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/).

The standard operation of the shell, remember, is to fork and run commands in child processes.

For best results, you should acclimate yourself to writing `run` scripts using something other than the shell, that *chain loads* daemon programs.  Here's your `run` script using [Laurent Bercot's `execline`](http://skarnet.org/software/execline/) instead of `/bin/sh` as the script interpreter:

```
#!/command/execlineb -PW
fdmove -c 2 1
/usr/bin/python /home/test/sigtest.py
```

`execline` doesn't have any of the overhead of all of the things that even non-interactive shells do, including parsing startup "rc" files.  And it comes with a useful suite of chain loading utilities for doing many of the things that one might want to do in `run` scripts.

But even `execline` does things that you don't need in a `run` script.  Hence the `-P` option to turn off *argument pushing*, which has no utility for `run` scripts.  Here's your `run` script using an even more barebones script interpreter, [my `nosh` program](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/Softwares/nosh.html):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/nosh
fdmove -c 2 1
/usr/bin/python /home/test/sigtest.py
```

Finally, here's your `run` script for `/bin/sh`, corrected:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec 2>&1
exec /usr/bin/python /home/test/sigtest.py
```

### Further reading

- https://superuser.com/a/708384/38062
- Russ Allbery (2013-12-18).  [*Bug#727708: upstart proposed policy in Debian*](https://lists.debian.org/debian-ctte/2013/12/msg00110.html).  debian-ctte.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2001).  "[Don't fork() in order to 'put the dæmon into the background'.](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/unix-daemon-design-mistakes-to-avoid.html#DoNotBackgroundise)".  *Mistakes to avoid when designing Unix dæmon programs*.   Frequently Given Answers.